# Get the value in a dataframe based on a value and a date in another dataframe

Tags: pandas

I tried countless answers to similar problems here on SO but couldn't find anything that works for this scenario. It's driving me nuts.

I have these two Dataframes:

df_op:

| index | Date | Close | Name | LogRet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-11-29 00:00:00 | 240.33 | MSFT | -0.0059 |
| 1 | 2022-11-29 00:00:00 | 280.57 | QQQ | -0.0076 |
| 2 | 2022-12-13 00:00:00 | 342.46 | ADBE | 0.0126 |
| 3 | 2022-12-13 00:00:00 | 256.92 | MSFT | 0.0173 |

df_quotes:

| index | Date | Close | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 72 | 2022-11-29 00:00:00 | 141.17 | AAPL |
| 196 | 2022-11-29 00:00:00 | 240.33 | MSFT |
| 73 | 2022-11-30 00:00:00 | 148.03 | AAPL |
| 197 | 2022-11-30 00:00:00 | 255.14 | MSFT |
| 11 | 2022-11-30 00:00:00 | 293.36 | QQQ |
| 136 | 2022-12-01 00:00:00 | 344.11 | ADBE |
| 198 | 2022-12-01 00:00:00 | **254.69** | MSFT |
| 12 | 2022-12-02 00:00:00 | 293.72 | QQQ |

I would like to add a column to df_op that indicates the close of the stock in df_quotes 2 days later. For example, the first row of df_op should become:

| index | Date | Close | Name | LogRet | Next |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-11-29 00:00:00 | 240.33 | MSFT | -0.0059 | 254.69 |

In other words:
for each row in df_op, find the corresponding Name in df_quotes with Date of 2 days later and copy its Close to df_op in column 'Next'.

I tried tens of combinations like this without success:

`df_quotes[df_quotes['Date'].isin(df_op['Date'] + pd.DateOffset(days=2)) & df_quotes['Name'].isin(df_op['Name'])]`

How can I do this without recurring to loops?

Comment: would the first line be the only one populated because no other value has a quote exactly 2 days later?

Comment: In this example yes, but in the full dataset there are plenty of cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#first convert to datetime
df_op['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_op['Date'])
df_quotes['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_quotes['Date'])


#merge on Date and Name, but the date is offset 2 business days
(pd.merge(df_op,
df_quotes[['Date','Close','Name']].rename({'Close':'Next'},axis=1),
left_on=['Date','Name'],
right_on=[df_quotes['Date'] - pd.tseries.offsets.BDay(2),'Name'],
how = 'left')
.drop(['Date_x','Date_y'],axis=1))
```

Output:

```
        Date  index   Close  Name  LogRet    Next
0 2022-11-29      0  240.33  MSFT -0.0059  254.69
1 2022-11-29      1  280.57   QQQ -0.0076     NaN
2 2022-12-13      2  342.46  ADBE  0.0126     NaN
3 2022-12-13      3  256.92  MSFT  0.0173     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to adjust it for holidays and ended up with this part: `pd.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(2, holidays=us_holidays)`. It works fine, but it warns that `Non-vectorized DateOffset being applied to Series or DatetimeIndex`. Any ideas on how to vectorize it?